# Conditional mean and variance related to Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

A lottery player decides to use a Poisson random variable generator to help him decide how many ticket to buy. He generates a Poisson random variable $N$ with mean $\lambda$, and then purchases $N$ lottery tickets. If each of the tickets he buys has (independently of the other tickets) the probability $p$ of winning, calculate the mean and the variance of the number of winning tickets the player buys.

Comment: Which reference on Poisson distributions do you use?

Comment: @did I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the amount of tickets he buys has a pmf $\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: Which textbooks do you follow, if you follow some? In other words: what can you do with Poisson distributions?

Comment: @did There isn't a specific textbook that I follow.

Comment: So... all you know is the definition of the Poisson distribution you reproduced in your comment?

Comment: @did I guess I'm not very familiar with Poisson random variables.

Comment: Nevertheless, surely you can compute the expected value of the number $W$ of winning tickets conditionally on $N=n$?

Comment: @did $E(W) = np$. Is that correct?

Comment: More precisely, E(W|N=n)=np. Hence E(W|N)=Np. Hence E(W)=...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6335/discussion-between-woaini-and-did)

Comment: @did Sorry, I can't seem to log in to use the chat. So would $E(W)=p(\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda})$?

Comment: Aaaargh, no! (But you seem to have a full bolts-on solution at your disposal, now.)

Comment: @did I looked through the other solution and I understand how martini arrived at it, but I still want to figure it out this way. If you don't mind, can you guide me through it a bit more?

Comment: Re the expectation, this can be quick: an important property of conditional expectations is the **tower property**, saying that E(E(U|V))=E(U) for every U and V. Here, E(W)=E(E(W|N))=E(Np)=pE(N)=pλ. Re the variance, one should start from an expression of E(W^2|N=n) and proceed similarly.

Comment: @did I'm trying to figure out what $E(W^2|N=n)$ equals, but unlike for $E(W|N=n)$ I can't seem to reason it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of winning tickets, we have for $k \in \mathbb N$
\begin{align*}
    P(X=k) &= \sum_{\ell=k}^\infty P(N=\ell, X=k)\\
           &= \sum_{\ell=k}^\infty P(X = k\mid N = \ell)P(N = \ell)\\
           &= \sum_{\ell=k}^\infty \binom{\ell}k p^k(1-p)^{\ell-k}\frac{\lambda^\ell}{\ell!}\exp(-\lambda)\\
           &= \frac {(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=k}^\infty \frac 1{(\ell-k)!}(\lambda - \lambda p)^{\ell-k}\exp(-\lambda)\\
           &= \frac {(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac 1{\ell!}(\lambda -\lambda p)^{\ell} \exp(-\lambda)\\
           &= \frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\exp(-\lambda) \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac 1{\ell!} \left({\lambda - \lambda p}\right)^\ell\\
           &= \frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\exp(-\lambda p)
\end{align*}
So we have $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda p)$, from here one can easily give $E(X) = \sigma^2(X) = \lambda p$.